# Browser can't access css, jquery resources using JSP and servlet

Tags: java, css, jsp

I am trying to add css and jquery resources using the following example: http://www.codejava.net/coding/jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-create-read-update-delete-crud-example.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<!--     <script src="app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<!--     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mybook.css" type="text/css" /> -->
    <base href="">
    **<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app-ajax.js"></script>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mybook.css" rel="stylesheet"** type="text/css">

    <title class="book">Books Store Application</title>
</head>
<body>
```

web.xml:

```
 <mime-mapping>    
            <extension>js</extension>        
            <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>        
        </mime-mapping>

        <mime-mapping>    
            <extension>css</extension>        
            <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>        
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>    
            <extension>jpg</extension>        
            <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>        
        </mime-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>jdbcURL</param-name>
            <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>jdbcUsername</param-name>
            <param-value>root</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>jdbcPassword</param-name>
            <param-value>xxx</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet- class>net.codejava.javaee.bookstore.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Using Chrome Developer tools I have noticed that jquery-1.10.2.js, app-ajax.js and mybook.css have html code instead of javascript and css!

jquery-1.10.2.js :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Xcb.jpg)

mybook.css  on Google chrome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biNZ4.jpg)

How is this problem caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: First thought: what IDE do you use for development? Did you publish you project correctly? I.e. if you added the jquery and app-ajax JS files to the project later (after the mybook.css), did you re-publish the project?

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8_102 , Tomcat 8.0.41 and Eclipse Neon.  Yes I redeployed the project many times after I added the css and jquery. I am wondering if the problem lies in the web.xml.